# How do the PhysWalking and similar functions actually handle input?

Tags: c++, physics, movement, unreal-4

As the title may suggest, I'm developing a `CustomMovementComponent` and I'm on the stage where I am developing my own `PhysCustom` function.

As such, I am trying to copy the style of Epic's development for these functions.

One thing that has bewildered me thus far is how these functions : `PhysWalking`, `PhysFalling` etc **actually handle input**.

I understand that they work based on time steps but where in these functions is the input actually taken into account?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question here, since I figured it out.

A Player's input is passed into `AddMovementInput`, which then affects `ControlInputVector`.

A `MovementComponent` then queries this `ControlInputVector` using `GetPendingInputVector`. It then uses the result of this to update/affect `Acceleration`.

The various `Phys` functions within `MovementComponent` will then query `Acceleration` (Henceforth known and used as input), to affect `Veclocity`, which is ticked and used to update the position of the `UpdatedComponent` for the player pawn.